# How to make a java class only available to one other class in a package

Tags: java

I have 3 classes, BST, Term, and WebPages.

BST is a binary search tree with Terms in each node.

WebPages instantiates a BST.

How can I ensure that the BST class is **only** available to the WebPages class? (that is a requirement of the project)

They should be in the same package, so the only thing that makes sense to me would be a nested class inside WebPages. Is there some other way to restrict access to an entire class so that only one other class in the same Package can "see" it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks Like ***inner class*** is the best alternative for you

Here is a quote from [JavaWorld](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077411/core-java/inner-classes.html) which descirbes exactly the same situation!

> For example, a tree class may have a method and many helper methods
>   that perform a search or walk of the tree. From an object-oriented
>   point of view, the tree is a tree, not a search algorithm. However,
>   you need intimate knowledge of the tree's data structures to
>   accomplish a search. An inner class allows us to remove that logic and
>   place it into its own class.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in other answers, the legitimate way to hide `BST` to `WebPages` exclusively is defining it as a static inner class:

```
public class WebPages {

    private static class BST {

    }
}
```

If you're content with defining `WebPages` in an independent package, you could put both classes in the same package but leave off the `public` class modifier for `BST`. You could even define both classes within the same file, `WebPages.java`, structured as follows:

```
public class WebPages {

}
class BST {

}
```

The downside to package-level hiding is that a new class could be written in the same package and gain access to `BST`.

Comment: Wouldn't the first example make `BST` available to all classes in the package? The inner class is more correct I think...

Comment: As Jeff says, I just tested the former and it's visible from other classes, so it does need to actually be an inner class.

Comment: You guys are right. I've never actually used this approach before so shame on me for not validating it first; I'll re-word it.